# Channel ID not being set in Akeneo when product created in UI, so not syncing via Akeneo - Magneto 2 connector. Has anyone had this issue?

Tags: magento, akeneo

Hello we have an Akeneo community V6 instance connected to a magento v2.4.5 instance using the Akeneo/Magento connector v103.3.1

We are seeing an issue that when we create a product in the Akeneo UI manually, the product doesn't not sync to magento. On investigation it looks like the Channel ID is not being set for the product in Akeneo.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? If so any ideas on how to resolve?
Thanks

Note: if we import the product via CSV this works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - data issue category not set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).